# Is there a way I can get google to cache a webpage when it is accessed by anyone? or any similar things?

Tags: html, caching

Lets say hypothetically that I want to access a website which I do not have access to. Is there a way I can get a google cache or any other caching website to cache when its accessed by someone? rather it be a forum post or anything of sort?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or code you've written

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: What would you suggest I post it under?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is use the Wayback Machine. If you're lucky it might save a page you're asking. I'm not entirely sure it's methods though but it seems like the more activity something has the more likely it's to be cached.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to capture it via snapshot using this link  http://web-capture.net/ or you could just paste the url to google and check if it is already cached which I guess your must have already done.